# Separate lists in nested list, and plotting first and second row values

Tags: python, list, plot, nested

I have a longer version of the list seen below, consisting of coordinates to different polygons (3 polygons in list below, 2000 in my actual list).

```
MainList = [[[-126.38493347032566, 8.065018490287665],
  [-126.37640789246038, 7.9425580414237755],
  [-126.29555487198307, 7.957675770047483],
  [-126.09180970014715, 7.757175961695489],
  [-126.24982282607408, 7.561646379709267],
  [-126.7162036678627, 7.309702635668215],
  [-126.85617174950822, 7.074462402268876],
  [-127.09392505521747, 7.227355837187626],
  [-127.13986378496843, 7.6147958544569665],
  [-127.29888183431987, 7.854024068113819],
  [-127.10320127147244, 8.123400890876232],
  [-127.18824938216802, 8.371078735837333],
  [-127.08770136961274, 8.394624626355522],
  [-126.51294868490649, 8.170702350367074],
  [-126.38493347032566, 8.065018490287665]],
 [[-127.82582769243184, 8.649146321871195],
  [-127.82674891366018, 8.59343262850995],
 [-127.97373872285344, 8.596277618944901],
  [-127.82582769243184, 8.649146321871195]],
 [[-128.12402462883344, 8.815270505675027],
  [-128.256760067403, 8.7946653101063],
  [-128.3467261891677, 8.940798405802703],
  [-128.25063346232488, 8.970663263189133],
  [-128.10796189381801, 8.891567942585386],
  [-128.12402462883344, 8.815270505675027]]]
```

I want to plot the first row values in the list in `MainList` as `x`, and second row as `y`.
Therefore I tried to flatlist `MainList`

```
flatlistTEST = [el for lst1 in MainList for lst2 in lst1 for el in lst2]
x_TEST, y_TEST = flatlistTEST[0::2],flatlistTEST[1::2]
```

when plotting this, `plt.plot(x_TEST,y_TEST)`:
[image: 3 polygons attaching lines]

The problem is, there is a line connecting each polygon to each other.

Edit:
I also tried without flatlisting it, but that would only plot the first polygon

```
x_test = [line[0] for line in MainList[0]]
y_test = [line[1] for line in MainList[0]]
plt.plot(x_test,y_test)
```

[Only 1 polygon plotted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVWzl.png)

How do I plot all 3 polygons, it without the line, each polygon separated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below should work nicely.

You do not need to flatten the list completely as in this case you want to maintain the x,y columns for the plot. So to separate the columns with a list comprehension on the nested MainList works and then you plot it.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
MainList = [[[-126.38493347032566, 8.065018490287665], [-126.37640789246038, 7.9425580414237755], [-126.29555487198307, 7.957675770047483], [-126.09180970014715, 7.757175961695489], [-126.24982282607408, 7.561646379709267], [-126.7162036678627, 7.309702635668215], [-126.85617174950822, 7.074462402268876], [-127.09392505521747, 7.227355837187626], [-127.13986378496843, 7.6147958544569665], [-127.29888183431987, 7.854024068113819], [-127.10320127147244, 8.123400890876232], [-127.18824938216802, 8.371078735837333], [-127.08770136961274, 8.394624626355522], [-126.51294868490649, 8.170702350367074], [-126.38493347032566, 8.065018490287665]],[[-127.82582769243184, 8.649146321871195], [-127.82674891366018, 8.59343262850995], [-127.97373872285344, 8.596277618944901], [-127.82582769243184, 8.649146321871195]],[[-128.12402462883344, 8.815270505675027], [-128.256760067403, 8.7946653101063], [-128.3467261891677, 8.940798405802703], [-128.25063346232488, 8.970663263189133], [-128.10796189381801, 8.891567942585386], [-128.12402462883344, 8.815270505675027]]]
x1_test = [line[0] for line in MainList[0]]
y1_test = [line[1] for line in MainList[0]]

x2_test = [line[0] for line in MainList[1]]
y2_test = [line[1] for line in MainList[1]]

x3_test = [line[0] for line in MainList[2]]
y3_test = [line[1] for line in MainList[2]]

plt.plot(x1_test, y1_test, color="green", label="first")
plt.plot(x2_test, y2_test, color="blue", label="second")
plt.plot(x3_test, y3_test, color="red", label="third")
```

A more generalised method that helps if you have a bigger list:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def polygons(main_list, list_index, color="black"):
    x1_test = [line[0] for line in main_list[list_index]]
    y1_test = [line[1] for line in main_list[list_index]]
    plt.plot(x1_test, y1_test, color=color)

for list_index in range(len(MainList)):
    polygons(main_list=MainList, list_index=list_index)
```

Comment: This sadly only plots the first polygon and not the remaining 2, but will add this to the main post as things I have tried, thanks.

Comment: ah ok, you have to plot 3. I will adjust my code to take into consideration all 3

Comment: Thanks, do you know if there is an easier way to plot it than type that code 3 times? Because my actual lists does not include 3 polygons, but 2000, and I would rather avoid typing that 2000 times if possible haha

Comment: hahaha yes that makes sense. you could make it into a function and then loop over it as the indexes are the same. i will add it below. I hope that helps